# Extremely slow printing for Kyocera FS-1320D on Wily Werewolf (15.10)

Tags: windows, printing, 15.10, pdf, cups-lpd

I have been experiencing slow printing issues with my Kyocera FS-1320D printer ever since I switched from Windows to Ubuntu. The printer is connected via USB.

The problem usually arises when it comes to medium or large-sized PDF files. It can easily take between 5-10 minutes to start printing, and the time lapse between one page and the next feels like forever. I often find myself forced to run a virtual XP machine, in which printing of the same exact file starts automatically. I installed the latest official drivers supplied by Kyocera (PPD version 8.4). Everything seems to be successfully configured in CUPS, as small PDF files or text-only documents can be printed without noticeble delay.

I get the feeling it must be something related to post-processing the document once it has been sent to print, as it tends to happen when PDF files contain images (e.g.: an export from PowerPoint). I would like to know if there is anything I could do to find the root of the problem, speed up the printing process and therefore avoid my dependance on Windows.